# Can I use Time-to-Live of mongoDB to delete an object in an array?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, ttl

All I can see on the internet was it will remove the whole document but I just want to delete the object in an array that is in a document.

Here is an example:

```
{
_id: "SOME ID OF A PARTICULAR DOCUMENT",
permission: [{
"I WANT TO DELETE THIS BASED ON TIME"
}],
"OTHER KEY-VALUE PAIRS"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible as of now. How about restructuring the schema to split each entry in array into separate documents?